# How to get bytes from interleave of numpy arrays with different dtype?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have two numpy arrays of different type

```
a = np.array([1, 3], dtype=np.int32)
b = np.array([[1.1, 4.4, 1.7],
              [1.1, 7.5, 8.2]], dtype=np.float32)
```

using `a.tobytes()` and `b.tobytes()` gives me the expected outputs:

```
# a.tobytes() is
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00'
# b.tobytes() is
b'\xcd\xcc\x8c?\xcd\xcc\x8c@\x9a\x99\xd9?\xcd\xcc\x8c?\x00\x00\xf0@33\x03A'
```

I would like to interleave the two like arrays to obtain bytes like this:

```
# The order I want is a[0] b[0] a[1] b[1].
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\x8c?\xcd\xcc\x8c@\x9a\x99\xd9?\x03\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\x8c?\x00\x00\xf0@33\x03A'
```

I tried using numpy because the code is not verbose and executes faster than my (successful but slow) for loop implementation.

```
ab = np.empty((2, 4), dtype=object)
ab[:, 0] = a
ab[:, 1:] = b

# ab will then be
array([[1, 1.100000023841858, 4.400000095367432, 1.7000000476837158],
       [3, 1.100000023841858, 7.5, 8.199999809265137]], dtype=object)
```

However I can't use `ab.tobytes()` anymore because the type `object` isn't even 32 bit anymore. The output is:

```
b"0'b\xfb\xfb\x7f\x00\x00p.\xaf`\x87\x01\x00\x00\xf0-\xaf`\x87\x01\x00\x00\x10&\xaf`\x87\x01\x00\x00p'b\xfb\xfb\x7f\x00\x00P,\xaf`\x87\x01\x00\x00P%\xaf`\x87\x01\x00\x00P)\xaf`\x87\x01\x00\x00"
```

Ultimately I want to write the bytes to a file.

Comment: Show your working list code.  `numpy` code isn't necessarily faster; if you are iterating, or working with object dtype arrays, list code may be faster.  How are you using this bytestring afterwards.  If it's awkward to generate, parsing will probably be even harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a slightly outrageous way to let just numpy handle all of it. Using `arr.tobytes()` gives us the bytes of a numpy array `arr`, naturally numpy has a function [`np.frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) doing the reverse.

Hence I can pretend my integer array is actually also made of floats:

```
ab = np.empty((2, 1 + 3), dtype=np.float32)
ab[:,0] = np.frombuffer(a.tobytes(), dtype=np.float32)
ab[:,1:] = b
ab.tobytes()
```

In my tests this was more than 7 times faster than Psidoms first solution, which was more than twice as fast as Psidoms second solution. Disclaimer, this includes writing the bytes to a file and some overhead.

EDIT: using [`numpy.ndarray.data`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.data.html) instead of [`numpy.ndarray.tobytes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) is even faster. `.tobytes` creates a variable containing the data, where as `.data` points to it in memory. So finally:

```
ab = np.empty((2, 1 + 3), dtype=np.float32)
ab[:,0] = np.frombuffer(a.data, dtype=np.float32)
ab[:,1:] = b
ab.data
```

Comment: "Disclaimer, this includes writing the bytes to a file and some overhead." - I don't see a file here.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I am referring to my actual implementation. The (dummy) code I have written here has not been timed on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You can always loop through the bytes by row, slice and concatenate the bytes from `a` and `b`.

```
a_bytes, a_row_size = a.tobytes(), a.dtype.itemsize
b_bytes, b_row_size = b.tobytes(), b.dtype.itemsize * b.shape[1]

res = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    res.append(a_bytes[a_row_size*i : a_row_size*(i+1)])
    res.append(b_bytes[b_row_size*i : b_row_size*(i+1)])

b''.join(res)
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\x8c?\xcd\xcc\x8c@\x9a\x99\xd9?\x03\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\x8c?\x00\x00\xf0@33\x03A'
```

Or create a structured array from `a` and `b` first, and then convert it to bytes:

```
data = [(x,) + tuple(y) for x, y in zip(a.tolist(), b.tolist())]
np.array(data, dtype='i, f, f, f').tobytes()

b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\x8c?\xcd\xcc\x8c@\x9a\x99\xd9?\x03\x00\x00\x00\xcd\xcc\x8c?\x00\x00\xf0@33\x03A'
```

Comment: Building up a bytestring with `+=` takes quadratic time.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Sure, had not thought about that.